# Is the following argument based on recurrence relations and floor functions valid?

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is the following inductive argument with recurrence relations valid?

**Let:**

- $x > 0$ be a real
- $t > 0$ be an integer
- $p_n$ be a $n$th prime
- $W_n(x)$ be the following [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation):

  > - $W_0(x) = x$
  > - $W_n(x) = W_{n-1}(x) - W_{n-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{p_n}\right)$
- $H_n(x)$ be the following recurrence relation:

  > - $H_0(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$
  > - $H_n(x) = H_{n-1}(x) - H_{n-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{p_n}\right)$
- $C_n(x)$ be the following recurrence relation:

  > - $C_0(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor = \left\{x\right\}$
  > - $C_n(x) = C_{n-1}(x) - C_{n-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{p_n}\right)$

**Observations:**

- $W_n(x) = H_n(x) + C_n(x)$ follows from:

  > - Base Case: $W_0(x) = x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\} = H_0(x) + C_0(x)$
  > - Assume $W_n(x) = H_n(x) + C_n(x)$
  > - $W_{n+1}(x) = W_n(x) - W_n\left(\dfrac{x}{p_n}\right) = H_n(x) + C_n(x) - H_n\left(\dfrac{x}{p_n}\right) - C_n\left(\dfrac{x}{p_n}\right) = H_{n+1}(x) + C_{n+1}(x)$
- $W_n\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) = \dfrac{W_n(x)}{t}$

  > - Base Case: $W_0\left(\dfrac{x}{t}\right) = \dfrac{x}{t} = \dfrac{W_0(x)}{t}$
  > - Assume $W_n\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) = \dfrac{W_n(x)}{t}$
  > - $W_{n+1}\left(\dfrac{x}{t}\right) = W_n\left(\dfrac{x}{t}\right) - W_n\left(\dfrac{x}{t p_{n+1}}\right) = \dfrac{W_n(x) - W_n\left(\dfrac{x}{p_{n+1}}\right)}{t} = \dfrac{W_{n+1}(x)}{t}$
- $W_n(x) < W_{n-1}(x)$

  > - Base Case: $W_1(x) = W_0(x) - W_0\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) = x - \dfrac{x}{2} = \dfrac{x}{2} < x$
  > - Assume $W_n(x) < W_{n-1}(x)$
  > - $W_{n+1}(x) = W_n(x) - W_n\left(\dfrac{x}{p_{n+1}}\right) = \dfrac{(p_{n+1}-1)W_n(x)}{p_{n+1}} < W_n(x)$

**Claim:**

$$-C_n(x) < H_n(x)$$

Here's the argument:

(1) Let $u$ be a real such that $u=p_{n+1}x$

(2) $H_{n+1}(u) + C_{n+1}(u) < H_n(u) + C_n(u)$

> Follows from $W_{n+1}(u) < W_n(u)$ and $W_n(u) = H_n(u) + C_n(u)$

(3) $C_{n+1}(u) - C_n(u) < H_n(u) - H_{n+1}(u)$

(4) $-C_n\left(\dfrac{u}{p_{n+1}}\right) < H_n\left(\dfrac{u}{p_{n+1}}\right)$

> Since $C_{n+1}(u) = C_n(u) - C_n\left(\dfrac{u}{p_{n+1}}\right)$ and $H_{n+1}(u) = H_n(u) - H_n\left(\dfrac{u}{p_{n+1}}\right)$

(5)  $-C_n(x) < H_n(x)$

---

Edit:

I had forgotten to call out that $x > 0$.

Comment: For the final bullet point you want $x>0$. Otherwise it appears to be fine. (I corrected two clear typos.)

Comment: Great point.  I meant to say $x$ is a positive real.  I'll update the argument.